# Unable to add a Webbrowser using the designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am trying to add a web browser control to a form but it gives me an odd error

[image: here is a screenshot for the error!]

Comment: Bitness? 64 bit control in 32 bit target?

Comment: What happens if you don't use the designer but add it through code?

Comment: i think spodger is spot on, try using target "x86/Any CPU" while designing and just switch to "x64" when building for releases.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?view=netframework-4.7.2